# In a PhoneGap application, does PhoneGrap translate my code into native code?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I just starting trying out PhoneGap today. I've heard about it before, and I've always thought it translated HTML and Javascript into native code. After trying it, I think the device is executing HTML/Javascript/CSS directly?

I'm confused as what PhoneGap does. Is my device executing raw HTML/Javascript/CSS or is it executing a translated native code?

By the way, I'm developing on Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PhoneGap executes your Javascript in the device's native browser.

It does not compile anything, although the browser's JITter probably will.